# search AES/CBC encrypted text

Tags: encryption, aes, cbc-mode

My system store user's email address to database with AES/CBC encryption. So all those email address stored in encrypted text (base64). And encrypted text is generated differently each time even plain text is same (it's CBC mode)

Is there any way to search email address only with substring of someone's email address from database?

e.g. searching 'myemail' from AES/CBC encrypted version of 'itsmyemail@email.com'

AFAK it is not possible, but I'm not sure is there any way that I don't know yet.

Comment: No it can't be done.  If you need to be able to query by email address then you don't encrypt them.

Answer (score 0):

Like you said, it's not possible to search email with substring or with SQL request using `like "%substring%"`.

The only search you can do is fulltext : `select * from your table where email="john.doe@email.com"`

To do this you can add a field in your table. This new field contains a HMAC of your clear value using a different AES key. One call it "blind index". So this field is indexed and when you want to search from a clear value you :

- Get an HMAC from your clear value to look for
- `select * from your table where email_blindindex="HMAC_value"`